# Shell script CSV processing - adding new column with AWK

Tags: bash, shell, csv, awk

I have a shell script which processes CSV file. One step in particular is adding a column and putting default value "null" in it. I got the expected change, its just that the new column to be added gets added to the next line instead of the same line.

Can anyone suggest whats wrong in the code and causing this unexpected change?

CODE:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=",";OFS=";"} {$(NF+1) = NR==1 ? "NewColm" : "NULL"} 1' source.csv > final.csv
```

Input CSV:

```
OldColm1,OldColm2,OldColm3,OldColm4,OldColm5,OldColm6
Value1,Value2,Value3,Value4,Value5,Value6
```

Output CSV:

```
OldColm1;OldColm2;OldColm3;OldColm4;OldColm5;OldColm6
;NewColm
Value1;Value2;Value3;Value4;Value5;Value6
;NULL
```

Expected CSV:

```
OldColm1;OldColm2;OldColm3;OldColm4;OldColm5;OldColm6;NewColm
Value1;Value2;Value3;Value4;Value5;Value6;NULL
```

Comment: Do you have CRLF line endings ? Also where is `value7` coming from ?

Comment: The value7 was written by mistake which i corrected now. I dont know how to identify CRLF line ending or CRLF

Comment: Use `cat -v file`. Look for `^M` at the end of lines.

Comment: Yes "^M" is there at the end of every line

Comment: Convert the file to UNIX format first `dos2unix source.csv`

Comment: Thanks m8 it works... a new thing i didnt knew...

Comment: If your source data always comes with CRLF line endings, you could also add `sub(/\r$/,"")` to your awk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the comments, this was caused by the lines being separated by `\r\n` instead of `\n`.

The `od` programm can be used to illustrate this:

```sh
cat source_dos.csv
```

```
OldColm1,OldColm2,OldColm3,OldColm4,OldColm5,OldColm6
Value1,Value2,Value3,Value4,Value5,Value6
```

```sh
od -c source_dos.csv
```

```
0000000   O   l   d   C   o   l   m   1   ,   O   l   d   C   o   l   m
0000020   2   ,   O   l   d   C   o   l   m   3   ,   O   l   d   C   o
0000040   l   m   4   ,   O   l   d   C   o   l   m   5   ,   O   l   d
0000060   C   o   l   m   6  \r  \n   V   a   l   u   e   1   ,   V   a
0000100   l   u   e   2   ,   V   a   l   u   e   3   ,   V   a   l   u
0000120   e   4   ,   V   a   l   u   e   5   ,   V   a   l   u   e   6
0000140  \r  \n
0000142
```

```sh
awk 'BEGIN{FS=",";OFS=";"}
     {$(NF+1) = NR==1 ? "NewColm" : "NULL"}
     1
    ' source_dos.csv
```

```
;NewColm;OldColm2;OldColm3;OldColm4;OldColm5;OldColm6
;NULL1;Value2;Value3;Value4;Value5;Value6
```

```sh
awk 'BEGIN{FS=",";OFS=";"}
     {$(NF+1) = NR==1 ? "NewColm" : "NULL"}
     1
    ' source_dos.csv | od -c
```

```
0000000   O   l   d   C   o   l   m   1   ;   O   l   d   C   o   l   m
0000020   2   ;   O   l   d   C   o   l   m   3   ;   O   l   d   C   o
0000040   l   m   4   ;   O   l   d   C   o   l   m   5   ;   O   l   d
0000060   C   o   l   m   6  \r   ;   N   e   w   C   o   l   m  \n   V
0000100   a   l   u   e   1   ;   V   a   l   u   e   2   ;   V   a   l
0000120   u   e   3   ;   V   a   l   u   e   4   ;   V   a   l   u   e
0000140   5   ;   V   a   l   u   e   6  \r   ;   N   U   L   L  \n
0000157
```

A <s>work-around</s> solution provided in the comments is to convert the input from `DOS`-like (`\r`) to `UNIX`-like (`\n`) input:

```sh
cp source_dos.csv source_unix.csv && dos2unix source_unix.csv
```

```
dos2unix: converting file source_unix.csv to Unix format ...
```

```sh
od -c source_unix.csv
```

```
0000000   O   l   d   C   o   l   m   1   ,   O   l   d   C   o   l   m
0000020   2   ,   O   l   d   C   o   l   m   3   ,   O   l   d   C   o
0000040   l   m   4   ,   O   l   d   C   o   l   m   5   ,   O   l   d
0000060   C   o   l   m   6  \n   V   a   l   u   e   1   ,   V   a   l
0000100   u   e   2   ,   V   a   l   u   e   3   ,   V   a   l   u   e
0000120   4   ,   V   a   l   u   e   5   ,   V   a   l   u   e   6  \n
0000140
```

```sh
awk 'BEGIN{FS=",";OFS=";"}
     {$(NF+1) = NR==1 ? "NewColm" : "NULL"}
     1
    ' source_unix.csv
```

```
OldColm1;OldColm2;OldColm3;OldColm4;OldColm5;OldColm6;NewColm
Value1;Value2;Value3;Value4;Value5;Value6;NULL
```

```sh
awk 'BEGIN{FS=",";OFS=";"}
     {$(NF+1) = NR==1 ? "NewColm" : "NULL"}
     1
    ' source_unix.csv | od -c
```

```
0000000   O   l   d   C   o   l   m   1   ;   O   l   d   C   o   l   m
0000020   2   ;   O   l   d   C   o   l   m   3   ;   O   l   d   C   o
0000040   l   m   4   ;   O   l   d   C   o   l   m   5   ;   O   l   d
0000060   C   o   l   m   6   ;   N   e   w   C   o   l   m  \n   V   a
0000100   l   u   e   1   ;   V   a   l   u   e   2   ;   V   a   l   u
0000120   e   3   ;   V   a   l   u   e   4   ;   V   a   l   u   e   5
0000140   ;   V   a   l   u   e   6   ;   N   U   L   L  \n
0000155
```

An `awk`-only solution to deal with this would be to adjust the *record separator* `RS` accordingly.

`RS`, as well as its counterpart the *output record separator* `ORS`, default to `\n`.
That's why in the `\r\n` input case, the `\r` remains part of the last input column and your new column gets 'stuck' in between this `\r` and the `\n` added as `ORS`.

Changing `RS` solves this:

```sh
awk 'BEGIN{RS="\r\n";FS=",";OFS=";"}
     {$(NF+1) = NR==1 ? "NewColm" : "NULL"}
     1
    ' source_dos.csv
```

```
OldColm1;OldColm2;OldColm3;OldColm4;OldColm5;OldColm6;NewColm
Value1;Value2;Value3;Value4;Value5;Value6;NULL
```

Note that this will still create `UNIX`-like (`\n`) output:

```sh
awk 'BEGIN{RS="\r\n";FS=",";OFS=";"}
     {$(NF+1) = NR==1 ? "NewColm" : "NULL"}
     1
    ' source_dos.csv | od -c
```

```
0000000   O   l   d   C   o   l   m   1   ;   O   l   d   C   o   l   m
0000020   2   ;   O   l   d   C   o   l   m   3   ;   O   l   d   C   o
0000040   l   m   4   ;   O   l   d   C   o   l   m   5   ;   O   l   d
0000060   C   o   l   m   6   ;   N   e   w   C   o   l   m  \n   V   a
0000100   l   u   e   1   ;   V   a   l   u   e   2   ;   V   a   l   u
0000120   e   3   ;   V   a   l   u   e   4   ;   V   a   l   u   e   5
0000140   ;   V   a   l   u   e   6   ;   N   U   L   L  \n
0000155
```

To generate `DOS`-like (`\r\n`) output, just adjust `ORS`, too:

```sh
awk 'BEGIN{RS="\r\n";ORS=RS;FS=",";OFS=";"}
     {$(NF+1) = NR==1 ? "NewColm" : "NULL"}
     1
    ' source_dos.csv
```

```
OldColm1;OldColm2;OldColm3;OldColm4;OldColm5;OldColm6;NewColm
Value1;Value2;Value3;Value4;Value5;Value6;NULL
```

```sh
awk 'BEGIN{RS="\r\n";ORS=RS;FS=",";OFS=";"}
     {$(NF+1) = NR==1 ? "NewColm" : "NULL"}
     1
    ' source_dos.csv | od -c
```

```
0000000   O   l   d   C   o   l   m   1   ;   O   l   d   C   o   l   m
0000020   2   ;   O   l   d   C   o   l   m   3   ;   O   l   d   C   o
0000040   l   m   4   ;   O   l   d   C   o   l   m   5   ;   O   l   d
0000060   C   o   l   m   6   ;   N   e   w   C   o   l   m  \r  \n   V
0000100   a   l   u   e   1   ;   V   a   l   u   e   2   ;   V   a   l
0000120   u   e   3   ;   V   a   l   u   e   4   ;   V   a   l   u   e
0000140   5   ;   V   a   l   u   e   6   ;   N   U   L   L  \r  \n
0000157
```

Note however that this will fail for `UNIX`-like (`\n`) input:

```sh
awk 'BEGIN{RS="\r\n";FS=",";OFS=";"}
     {$(NF+1) = NR==1 ? "NewColm" : "NULL"}
     1
    ' source_unix.csv
```

```
OldColm1;OldColm2;OldColm3;OldColm4;OldColm5;OldColm6
Value1;Value2;Value3;Value4;Value5;Value6
;NewColm
```

```sh
awk 'BEGIN{RS="\r\n";FS=",";OFS=";"}
     {$(NF+1) = NR==1 ? "NewColm" : "NULL"}
     1
    ' source_unix.csv | od -c
```

```
0000000   O   l   d   C   o   l   m   1   ;   O   l   d   C   o   l   m
0000020   2   ;   O   l   d   C   o   l   m   3   ;   O   l   d   C   o
0000040   l   m   4   ;   O   l   d   C   o   l   m   5   ;   O   l   d
0000060   C   o   l   m   6  \n   V   a   l   u   e   1   ;   V   a   l
0000100   u   e   2   ;   V   a   l   u   e   3   ;   V   a   l   u   e
0000120   4   ;   V   a   l   u   e   5   ;   V   a   l   u   e   6  \n
0000140   ;   N   e   w   C   o   l   m  \n
0000151
```

Why I think this is better than using `dos2unix`:
Using a *regular expression* (RE) as `RS` one can make it work for both `\n` *and* `\r\n`-separated input **without the need to know which of the two it is**:

```sh
awk 'BEGIN{RS="\r?\n";FS=",";OFS=";"}
     {$(NF+1) = NR==1 ? "NewColm" : "NULL"}
     1
    ' source_dos.csv
```

```
OldColm1;OldColm2;OldColm3;OldColm4;OldColm5;OldColm6;NewColm
Value1;Value2;Value3;Value4;Value5;Value6;NULL
```

```sh
awk 'BEGIN{RS="\r?\n";FS=",";OFS=";"}
     {$(NF+1) = NR==1 ? "NewColm" : "NULL"}
     1
    ' source_unix.csv
```

```
OldColm1;OldColm2;OldColm3;OldColm4;OldColm5;OldColm6;NewColm
Value1;Value2;Value3;Value4;Value5;Value6;NULL
```

In both cases, `UNIX`-like (`\n`) output will be generated:

```sh
awk 'BEGIN{RS="\r?\n";FS=",";OFS=";"}
     {$(NF+1) = NR==1 ? "NewColm" : "NULL"}
     1
    ' source_dos.csv | od -c
```

```
0000000   O   l   d   C   o   l   m   1   ;   O   l   d   C   o   l   m
0000020   2   ;   O   l   d   C   o   l   m   3   ;   O   l   d   C   o
0000040   l   m   4   ;   O   l   d   C   o   l   m   5   ;   O   l   d
0000060   C   o   l   m   6   ;   N   e   w   C   o   l   m  \n   V   a
0000100   l   u   e   1   ;   V   a   l   u   e   2   ;   V   a   l   u
0000120   e   3   ;   V   a   l   u   e   4   ;   V   a   l   u   e   5
0000140   ;   V   a   l   u   e   6   ;   N   U   L   L  \n
0000155
```

```sh
awk 'BEGIN{RS="\r?\n";FS=",";OFS=";"}
     {$(NF+1) = NR==1 ? "NewColm" : "NULL"}
     1
    ' source_unix.csv | od -c
```

```
0000000   O   l   d   C   o   l   m   1   ;   O   l   d   C   o   l   m
0000020   2   ;   O   l   d   C   o   l   m   3   ;   O   l   d   C   o
0000040   l   m   4   ;   O   l   d   C   o   l   m   5   ;   O   l   d
0000060   C   o   l   m   6   ;   N   e   w   C   o   l   m  \n   V   a
0000100   l   u   e   1   ;   V   a   l   u   e   2   ;   V   a   l   u
0000120   e   3   ;   V   a   l   u   e   4   ;   V   a   l   u   e   5
0000140   ;   V   a   l   u   e   6   ;   N   U   L   L  \n
0000155
```

To set the output type according to the input type, the `ORS` can be set per record to the actual text that matched the `RS` RE, `RT`:

```sh
awk 'BEGIN{RS="\r?\n";FS=",";OFS=";"}
     {ORS=RT}
     {$(NF+1) = NR==1 ? "NewColm" : "NULL"}
     1
    ' source_dos.csv
```

```
OldColm1;OldColm2;OldColm3;OldColm4;OldColm5;OldColm6;NewColm
Value1;Value2;Value3;Value4;Value5;Value6;NULL
```

```sh
awk 'BEGIN{RS="\r?\n";FS=",";OFS=";"}
     {ORS=RT}
     {$(NF+1) = NR==1 ? "NewColm" : "NULL"}
     1
    ' source_unix.csv
```

```
OldColm1;OldColm2;OldColm3;OldColm4;OldColm5;OldColm6;NewColm
Value1;Value2;Value3;Value4;Value5;Value6;NULL
```

```sh
awk 'BEGIN{RS="\r?\n";FS=",";OFS=";"}
     {ORS=RT}
     {$(NF+1) = NR==1 ? "NewColm" : "NULL"}
     1
    ' source_dos.csv | od -c
```

```
0000000   O   l   d   C   o   l   m   1   ;   O   l   d   C   o   l   m
0000020   2   ;   O   l   d   C   o   l   m   3   ;   O   l   d   C   o
0000040   l   m   4   ;   O   l   d   C   o   l   m   5   ;   O   l   d
0000060   C   o   l   m   6   ;   N   e   w   C   o   l   m  \r  \n   V
0000100   a   l   u   e   1   ;   V   a   l   u   e   2   ;   V   a   l
0000120   u   e   3   ;   V   a   l   u   e   4   ;   V   a   l   u   e
0000140   5   ;   V   a   l   u   e   6   ;   N   U   L   L  \r  \n
0000157
```

```sh
awk 'BEGIN{RS="\r?\n";FS=",";OFS=";"}
     {ORS=RT}
     {$(NF+1) = NR==1 ? "NewColm" : "NULL"}
     1
    ' source_unix.csv | od -c
```

```
0000000   O   l   d   C   o   l   m   1   ;   O   l   d   C   o   l   m
0000020   2   ;   O   l   d   C   o   l   m   3   ;   O   l   d   C   o
0000040   l   m   4   ;   O   l   d   C   o   l   m   5   ;   O   l   d
0000060   C   o   l   m   6   ;   N   e   w   C   o   l   m  \n   V   a
0000100   l   u   e   1   ;   V   a   l   u   e   2   ;   V   a   l   u
0000120   e   3   ;   V   a   l   u   e   4   ;   V   a   l   u   e   5
0000140   ;   V   a   l   u   e   6   ;   N   U   L   L  \n
0000155
```

Note that using an `RE` as `RS` as well as the `RT` *built-in variable* are GNU `awk` (`gawk`) extensions and might not be supported by all `awk` implementations.